# Font Awesome icons not working in Firefox

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I am trying understand what it is going on, I am using font-awesome  and 2 icons not load at all in Firefox, can you guys help me to solve it?

if you open the jsfiddle you will see works on chrome but not in firefox.

icons not working are:

```
fa-user-circle-o
fa-calendar-plus-o
```

icon working: `fa fa-pencil-square-o`

**Tested in:**

Firefox 55.0.2 (64-bit) for Ubuntu

Chrome Version 58.0.3029.96 (64-bit) for Ubuntu

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/s15dxabc/4/

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<br><br>
<i class="fa-calendar-plus-o"></i>
<br><br>
<i class="fa-user-circle-o"></i>
<br><br>
<i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i>
```

Comment: check your icon here. http://fontawesome.io/icons/

Comment: Looks the same in FF and Chrome

Comment: Just add ' fa ' class , as per the font-awsome structure you need to follow the given syntax.

Answer (score 7):

Here is the updated js fiddle `https://jsfiddle.net/s15dxabc/6/`
You forgot to add `.fa` class

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<br><br>
<i class="fa fa-calendar-plus-o"></i>
<br><br>
<i class="fa fa-user-circle-o"></i>
<br><br>
<i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i>
```

Answer (score 0):

All fontawesome icons need the `fa` class too.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<br><br>
<i class="fa fa-calendar-plus-o"></i>
<br><br>
<i class="fa fa-user-circle-o"></i>
<br><br>
<i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i>
```

Answer (score 0):

See the updated Fiddle :

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s15dxabc/5/)

```
<br><br>
<i class="fa fa-calendar-plus-o"></i>

<br><br>
<i class="fa fa-user-circle-o"></i>

<br><br>
<i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the fa class on the two first elements.

https://jsfiddle.net/s15dxabc/8/

Should be:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<br><br>
<i class="fa fa-calendar-plus-o"></i>
<br><br>
<i class="fa fa-user-circle-o"></i>
<br><br>
<i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<br><br>
<i class="fa fa-calendar-plus-o"></i>
<br><br>
<i class="fa fa-user-circle-o"></i>
<br><br>
<i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i>
```

Comment: simply providing code is not a good way of answering questions here.. Kindly provide some explanation to support your code. Check this link which tells you [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).